# Windows 10 Update 1 breaks Visual Studio 2013 Silverlight Lightswitch app

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am using Windows 10 machine with Visual Studio 2013 Lightswitch project.

I was working on the project and it was working perfectly. However I decided to run Windows Update (which includes that big Windows 10 Update 1). Big mistake. Afterwards I can open but cannot run the Lightswitch application in Visual Studio 2013 anymore.

This is the error message I get:
[image]

When I follow that [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=146060) it downloads Silverlight.exe (5.5.0031). However when I run it as Administrator I get the following:
[image]

Things I have tried

- Restarted machine
- Try a backup copy of the Lightswitch app

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it. Solution is to reinstall Silverlight.

I went to Control Panel-Add Programs and Features. Uninstalled the item called "Silverlight". I did not uninstall the Silverlight SDK entries.

Afterwards I ran that installer from the [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=146060) in my original question and that caused it to work.